# Word add-in won't install

Tags: ms-office, office-js

I'm working on an add-in used in Word (already published and used). Our requirements are Word 2016 but that should be it as far as I know. Usually, when we had users complaining about not being able to install our add-in, it turned out they had an older version of Word etc.

This is in our manifest file:

```
<Requirements>
  <Sets DefaultMinVersion="1.1">
    <Set Name="WordApi" MinVersion="1.1"/>
    <Set Name="DialogApi" MinVersion="1.1"/>
  </Sets>
</Requirements>
```

This client has the following:

- Commercial License of Office 2016
- Office Professional Plus

When installing the add-in, they get the message: `version of Word is not compatible`. When installing other add-ins, the client claims they install fine.

Could this be on their end (and if yes, why?) or is there something that can be done on our end (for instance, in the manifest file) to make our add-in more compatible with all versions of 2016 Word?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Support for DialogAPI 1.1 and WordAPI 1.1 depends on the build of Office 2016 being used.

If your client is using a click2run install, they need to be on Version 1602 (Build 6741.0000) or later
If they are using an MSI install, they need to be on Build 16.0.4390.1000 or later

For more information on DialogAPI support requirements, see [here](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/requirement-sets/dialog-api-requirement-sets), for WordAPI support requirements, see [here](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/requirement-sets/word-api-requirement-sets)